# I am trying to load multiple csv files from multiple paths from my network drive to python for pre processing

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, automation, configuration-files, network-drive

How to create a configuration feed file with all the folder paths to look for and read that config file through python?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a config.py file to save all your configuration values like

-----config.py------------

```
filename = "testnames.xlsx"
sheet_name = "WRDS"
```

To use it in your actual py file

-------------actual file-----------------

```
import config as cfg
file_name = cfg.filename
sheet_name = cfg.sheet_name
```